# Maven compilation error upgrading JDK6 to JDK8

Tags: java, maven, build

When compiling using JDK 6 compilation is successful, when updating to use the latest JDK (1.8.0.25) then we get the following errors:

```
Error Log from complication with JDK 8

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
 Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 07:51:28-0600)
 Maven home: /usr/local/mvn
 Java version: 1.8.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0/jre
 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8

 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project sakai-announcement-tool: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
 [ERROR] /home/mustansar/source/sakai-10.x/announcement/announcement-tool/tool/src/java/org/sakaiproject/announcement/entityprovider/AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.java:[276,4] error: cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol: method setTitle(String)
 [ERROR] location: variable da of type AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.DecoratedAnnouncement
 [ERROR] /home/mustansar/source/sakai-10.x/announcement/announcement-tool/tool/src/java/org/sakaiproject/announcement/entityprovider/AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.java:[277,4] error: cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol: method setBody(String)
 [ERROR] location: variable da of type AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.DecoratedAnnouncement
 [ERROR] /home/mustansar/source/sakai-10.x/announcement/announcement-tool/tool/src/java/org/sakaiproject/announcement/entityprovider/AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.java:[278,4] error: cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol: method setCreatedByDisplayName(String)
 [ERROR] location: variable da of type AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.DecoratedAnnouncement
 [ERROR] /home/mustansar/source/sakai-10.x/announcement/announcement-tool/tool/src/java/org/sakaiproject/announcement/entityprovider/AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.java:[279,4] error: cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol: method setCreatedOn(Date)
 [ERROR] location: variable da of type AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.DecoratedAnnouncement
 [ERROR] /home/mustansar/source/sakai-10.x/announcement/announcement-tool/tool/src/java/org/sakaiproject/announcement/entityprovider/AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.java:[280,4] error: cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol: method setSiteId(String)
 [ERROR] location: variable da of type AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.DecoratedAnnouncement
 [ERROR] /home/mustansar/source/sakai-10.x/announcement/announcement-tool/tool/src/java/org/sakaiproject/announcement/entityprovider/AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.java:[281,4] error: cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol: method setSiteTitle(String)
 [ERROR] location: variable da of type AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.DecoratedAnnouncement
 [ERROR] /home/mustansar/source/sakai-10.x/announcement/announcement-tool/tool/src/java/org/sakaiproject/announcement/entityprovider/AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.java:[291,4] error: cannot find symbol
```

This error is present regardless if we set the maven source version to 1.6 or keep it at 1.8. The classes that cannot be found are our own, not JDK specific. I don't see any pattern in which classes cannot be found vs ones that can be, as most are in the same projects and all are on src/main/java

edit:

maven compiler plugin:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2</version>
          <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What does your pom.xml look like for your maven-compiler-plugin?

Comment: You should have a look at this source `AnnouncementEntityProviderImpl.java:[276,4]`

Comment: It looks as though it's *methods* that it can't find, not classes.

Comment: Correct, it is methods that it cannot find, that when you look at the source are clearly there and valid.

Comment: Grasping at straws here, but... you are doing a clean build each time? Have you compared the effective classpath running each way, looking for differences? You should be able to compare easily enough by capturing the output of "mvn -X compile" each way. I would take the error message seriously--the compiler can't find the methods for some reason and you need to suss it out.

Comment: Yes, I am doing a clean build (or install) each time. -X flag does not return anything useful.